# Leaflet plugin version compatibiliy

Tags: leaflet

I plan to upgrade the Leaflet version. But I uses alot of plugins in my project. How can I make sure all the plugin is compatible to the latest Leaflet version?
How to find out which version they are compatible with?

Comment: See their doc. If not specified, then just try. Without any detail on the plugins and their old and new versions, I do not see what else we can help you with.

Comment: So, I need to check the individual plugins 1 by 1 . I see :( 
I thought Leaflet will at least have some centralized record/list/documentations for that. They listed all plugins here : https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html but without specifying the version supported or which is obsolete. =_= I think Leaflet should enforce the developer that build the plugin to provide such information

Comment: It is true that some big Open Source projects are funded by wealthy companies, and others are sponsored by many users, but the vast majority is created on people's limited extra time. But this is Open Source, so please do contribute! :-)